# How to bypass an express middleware?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, http, express

I'm working with an express application. There are some express routes, as

```
 server.get('*' , ... )
```

etc. which perform some common operations: authentication, validation... etc.

they also decorates the response with meaningful information: i.e. in every request to the server it gives not only the expected json/html, but also information regarding the user, some app metadata that the front-end consumes etc. etc.

Let's say all this extra metadata cames in a field called `extradata` in **every** request to the server.

Now, there is a bug that is causing a problem: instead of returning its expected response (a json with a bunch of system logs), is sending **only** this `extradata` field.

I'm pretty confident the problem is in one of the middlewares, because that code that sends the response in this case is really simple, it's just a `res.send()` of a json. So I believe this part of the app is requiring some module that sets a middleware which causes the error. There are **a lot** of global vars and implicit parameters in the app so is really difficult to debug it manualluy.

I attempted to bypass such middlewares programmatically, like:

```
delete server._router.stack[2];
```

but is causing an `TypeError: Cannot read property 'route' of undefined` and thus preventing my app to build: sure this is not the way to go.

so, **is there a way to programmatically ignore or bypass express routes that are yet set**?

Even better, **is there a way to programmatically tap into express middlewares and log every request and response**?

(afaik, there are libreries like [morgan](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan) that logs every request, but I don't think they apply to this case since I need to discriminate between middlewares).

Comment: Seriously, you need to get a hold of the code and document every middleware that is being used to make yourself a list to investigate.  You shouldn't be trying to fix this problem by dynamically reaching into the router stack and deleting middleware handlers.  You should understand each and every middleware that is installed, make a list of suspects, investigate each one, isolate the one causing the problem and fix it or remove it from your code for good.  Do some real problem solving and real fixing, not guess and test pokes in the dark.

Comment: FYI, a simple recursive grep for `app.use` or `router.use` or even just `.use(` should give you a starting point for all typical middleware installations.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @jfriend00! Problem is, there are a lot of files in the codebase, which have `server.get`, `server.use`, `app.get`, `express.use` etc. etc. etc. and I don't know if they were called in this particular run of my program -since several different web applications share the same repository-. Also, since there is a heavy dependence on globals, is pretty difficult to grasp if a particular file will be used in an app just by looking statically. **I realize that this is actually a severe problem** that should be addressed seriously, but I have no such permissions.

Comment: If you do need to test without a middleware function, use `next()` in it. Possibly with an `if` condition for whatever requests you are testing.

Comment: If you need to fix such a severe problem, then get the right permissions to properly attack the problem.  An unfortunate saying in software development: "There's never enough time to do it the right way at the beginning, but always enough time to do it over when the quick and dirty way didn't work".  Fix this the right way.  Methodical understanding and analysis of the code base to find the specific culprit.

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/debugging.html

Answer (score 1):

What I generally do is simply use the next method. You can access it by simply passing it to the callback function. Something like:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if(...) {
    next();
  } else {
    ...
  }
}
```

What this is going to do is go to the **next** middleware.

So if I understand correctly, you can check what you exactly need in the if-statement and do things accordingly.

What I would suggest is you read the Express API documentation, especially the section about middleware, which you can find [here](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html). Moreover, try to isolate the suspects and solve the issue by removing the problem, rather than deleting handlers and trying to solve the problem the easy way.